# TreeMap to ArrayList<Double> throws java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

I have a TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>
```

that's returned from a class. I create an

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>
```

from that TreeMap like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> importedTreeMap = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(importedDataAsTreeMap.values());
```

From here on, I would like to access the data in `importedTreeMap`, and add it to some other ArrayLists. Only problem is, this does not seem to be possible.

My code is like this:

```
dbImport.readDataDecimal(selected.toString());
importedDataAsTreeMap = dbImport.getDbData();

ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> importedTreeMap = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(importedDataAsTreeMap.values());

ArrayList<Double> latestImport = new ArrayList<Double>(importedTreeMap.get(importedTreeMap.size()-1)); 

System.out.println(latestImport.get(0));

ArrayList<Double> test = new ArrayList<Double>();
test.add(latestImport.get(0));
```

The output from the `println` looks like this:

```
 [12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0]
```

and that is what I want to add to my ArrayList "test", but doing so throws:

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

How to get around this problem?

Comment: Do you have a loop somewhere? Just printing a double shouldn't print out this: [12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0].

Comment: The output from the `println` should be `12.0`, not `[12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0]`.  Something is very confused.  Either your map should just be `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>`, your `importedTreeMap` should be _three_ `ArrayList`s deep, or you'll need to concatenate them to two levels deep somewhere else.

Comment: Please **copy and paste your code as is without any modification** into the question. It does not seem like you did.

Comment: I have made an update, with the actual code now @Dukeling 
I have no loops. 

Something is very wrong - just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: No problems in [my little test](http://ideone.com/jCC771). I still think you're not showing us the actual code. If that's too long or there's a privacy concern, construct a **minimum test case** that reproduces the problem (tested on your computer) (like I did above) and **copy and paste (don't rewrite it) all that code as is** in the question.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It seems like you are right. Adding one more `ArrayList` seems to do the trick!

Comment: @Dukeling You are right, it is in the middle of a big GUI. And there are some other classes to this as well - anyway: thank you all very much for the help!